# C-operator precedence confusion

Tags: c

```
main()
{
  int a=3+2%5;
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

The program returns value 5, but how & why?

Comment: How come you're asking that if you know that it's about operator precedence?

Answer (score 5):

Because your arithmetic expression parses as `3+(2%5)`.

See this [table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm), and note that % is higher precedence than +.

Answer (score 1):

`%` has higher [`precedence`](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than `+` so

```
3 + 2 % 5
```

is equivalent to

```
3 + ( 2 % 5 )
```

which gives `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
main() { 
    int a = 3 + (2 % 5); 
    printf("%d",a); 
}
```

See [operator precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).

`2 % 5` (=2) is evaluated first, followed by `3 + 2`, hence the answer `5`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, '%' binds more than '+'.

```
3+2%5
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
3+(2%5)
```

which is obviously 5

Answer (score 0):

Because it's interpreted as `3 + (2 % 5)`. When you divide `2` by `5`, the remainder is `2` and adding that to the `3` gives you `5`.

The *reason* it's interpreted that way is in section `6.5.5` of the [ISO C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

```
multiplicative-expression:
    cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression * cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression / cast-expression
    multiplicative-expression % cast-expression
```

In other words, `%` is treated the same as `*` and `/` and therefore has a higher operator precedence than `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Modulus is evaluated at the same precedence as multiplication and division.

```
2 % 5 = 2
2 + 3 = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The mod operator(%) has precedence over the addition operator and hence '2%5' gets calculated first resulting in 2 and then 3 + 2 is calculated resulting in your answer 5.